# Do Half-Castes preserve their caste charms if they Exalt as another type of Exalt?

Tags: exalted, exalted-2e

According to Scroll Of Heroes Half-Castes can progress up to Essence 3 and learn their celestial caste parents charms but I am imagining a situation where a Lunar seduces a dragon blooded in some spy mission and procreates with them. Their child would be a Lunar half-caste but carry the potential to Exalt as a dragonblooded? I am aware that Exaltation removes any mutations that the half-caste may have but would that purge the incompatible charms as well or could there be a dragon blooded with Lunar/Solar charms?

Comment: Please note that term has been removed in Exalted 3e because it's an ethnic slur.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that it was an ethnic slur. I apologize though. Should I delete the question or change the wording?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 108 of Scroll Of Heroes says that a half-caste cannot ever Exalt as another caste due to the fact that the destiny in their blood has already pledged to Unconquered Sun/Luna/Yozi even before they are born.